# Search CSV file by row column

Tags: python

Hi I was wondering if there is a way to search a CSV file without importing CSV module to search by row and column.

Also how could I use re.findall to find instances of a word in a column or row

For example the genre is Horror and the movie title starts with The ..so I'd need to find the total amount of "The" movies in the horror genre

Thanks

Comment: pandas is probably the best way to handle csv's and search columns or rows. if you don't want to import the csv module, are you unwilling to import pandas?

Comment: I'd like to search by row colum without importing csv or using panda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be not the best solution but it works. Let's imagine you have a `films.csv` file with film name and author like this:

```
title, author
The dogs, author1
The cats, author2
Cars, author1
Houses, author3
The apples, Jobs
```

If you want to count the number of occurrences of film name starting by "The":

```
with open('films.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
n = len(re.findall("The*", data))
```

Comment: Thanks pac for your help